# Merge Overlapping Time Intervals based on Hierarchy in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to solve a problem where i want to merge overlapping intervals for a given column id, but i also want to merge them based on hierarchy/priority. I have start_time and stop_time for each interval and each interval has a hierarchy/priority associated with it.

These are the following columns in the table:

```
id, start_time, stop_time, priority
```

I was able to solve the problem where i do not have take into account the priority, but i am struggling with this one.

```
Red colour: p1 (priority 1)
Blue Colour: p2 (priority 2)
Green colour: p3 (priority 3)
```

Note that in the example input below we will have 9 rows having same id, and the output will have 6 rows. Please note that for some id's might have only some of the priority values or just one, the solution should take care of that.

expected input and output:

[image: expected input and output]

Comment: MySQL or BigQuery?  They are quite different.

Comment: Typical "gaps & islands" problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Bigquery. added some details

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please also not that i need to combine these for a given id.

Comment: I modified my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH check_times AS (
  SELECT id, start_time AS time FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT id, stop_time AS time FROM `project.dataset.table` 
), distinct_intervals AS (
  SELECT id, time AS start_time, LEAD(time) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) stop_time
  FROM check_times
), deduped_intervals AS (
  SELECT a.id, a.start_time, a.stop_time, MIN(priority) priority
  FROM distinct_intervals a
  JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
  ON a.id = b.id 
  AND a.start_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.stop_time 
  AND a.stop_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.stop_time
  GROUP BY a.id, a.start_time, a.stop_time
), combined_intervals AS (
  SELECT id, MIN(start_time) start_time, MAX(stop_time) stop_time, ANY_VALUE(priority) priority 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, start_time, stop_time, priority, COUNTIF(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT id, start_time, stop_time, priority, 
        start_time != IFNULL(LAG(stop_time) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time), start_time) OR
        priority != IFNULL(LAG(priority) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time), -1) flag
      FROM deduped_intervals
    )
  )
  GROUP BY id, grp
)
SELECT *
FROM combined_intervals
-- ORDER BY id, start_time
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  - result is

[image]

> Can you also share a solution where we merge intervals based on just id and no priority column

I just simply slightly adjusted above query to ignore priority

```
#standardSQL
WITH check_times AS (
  SELECT id, start_time AS TIME FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT id, stop_time AS TIME FROM `project.dataset.table` 
), distinct_intervals AS (
  SELECT id, TIME AS start_time, LEAD(TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TIME) stop_time
  FROM check_times
), deduped_intervals AS (
  SELECT a.id, a.start_time, a.stop_time 
  FROM distinct_intervals a
  JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
  ON a.id = b.id 
  AND a.start_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.stop_time 
  AND a.stop_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.stop_time
  GROUP BY a.id, a.start_time, a.stop_time
), combined_intervals AS (
  SELECT id, MIN(start_time) start_time, MAX(stop_time) stop_time 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, start_time, stop_time, COUNTIF(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT id, start_time, stop_time, 
        start_time != IFNULL(LAG(stop_time) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time), start_time) flag
      FROM deduped_intervals
    )
  )
  GROUP BY id, grp
)
SELECT *
FROM combined_intervals
-- ORDER BY id, start_time
```

with result

```
Row id  start_time  stop_time    
1   1   0           36   
2   1   41          47
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikhail, works perfect. I am gonna test it on some more sample data to verify the solution.

Comment: sure. have in mind - the answer is based on logic and sample data you presented in your question. so if you will get into case that is not covered - please post new question. meantime consider voting up and if confirmed working - come back and accept :o)

Comment: Can you also share a solution where we merge intervals based on just id and no priority column. I wanna see how it performs with respect to the solution i came up with. I want to compare the run time as the data i am dealing with is quite large. Thanks.

Comment: added this to my answer

Comment: Hi @Mikhail in the second solution(merging without taking into priority) is it possible to modify the solution so that we one more column priority which is max value of priority within that time period? so we will have an extra priority column with value 3 for row 1 (0 to 36 duration) and value 2 for row 2 (41 to 47 duration).

Comment: @ParveshAngrula - if you have new question - please post new question and we will be happy to help you

Comment: posted a new question as you suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498923/merge-overlapping-intervals-and-track-maximum-value-in-bigquery-sql

Comment: @ParveshAngrula - sure. i will check it shortly, unless someone will answer it by that time :o)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: btw. I answered that question

Answer (score -1):

This is a "combining" islands problem. One solution is to find where the islands begin and do a cumulative sum of the beginnings.  You can determine the beginning by seeing where there are no overlaps:

```
select id, priority, min(start_time), max(stop_time)
from (select t.*,
             countif(coalesce(prev_stop_time, stop_time) < stop_time) over (partition by id, priority order by start_time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(stop_time) over (partition by id, priority order by start_time rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_stop_time
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by id, priority, grp;
```