# Merge Overlapping Intervals and Track Maximum Value in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to solve a problem where i want to merge overlapping intervals for a given column id, but i also want to track the maximum value for each overlapped interval. I have start_time and stop_time for each interval and each interval has a hierarchy/priority associated with it.

These are the following columns in the table:
id, start_time, stop_time, some_value

example input:

[image]

example output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and I assume you stll working on the same use-case as in previous question, so I wanted to keep it inline with that solution - and you can extend it for when you also want to account for priorities for example

So, anyway:

```
#standardSQL
WITH check_times AS (
  SELECT id, start_time AS TIME FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT id, stop_time AS TIME FROM `project.dataset.table` 
), distinct_intervals AS (
  SELECT id, TIME AS start_time, LEAD(TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TIME) stop_time
  FROM check_times
), deduped_intervals AS (
  SELECT a.id, a.start_time, a.stop_time, MAX(some_value) some_value 
  FROM distinct_intervals a
  JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
  ON a.id = b.id 
  AND a.start_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.stop_time 
  AND a.stop_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.stop_time
  GROUP BY a.id, a.start_time, a.stop_time
), combined_intervals AS (
  SELECT id, MIN(start_time) start_time, MAX(stop_time) stop_time, MAX(some_value) some_value 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, start_time, stop_time, some_value, COUNTIF(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT id, start_time, stop_time, some_value,
        start_time != IFNULL(LAG(stop_time) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time), start_time) flag
      FROM deduped_intervals
    )
  )
  GROUP BY id, grp
)
SELECT *
FROM combined_intervals
-- ORDER BY id, start_time
```

If to apply to your sample data - result is

```
Row id  start_time  stop_time   some_value   
1   1   0           36          50   
2   1   41          47          23
```

> Is it possible to add one more column to the result which will show number of events during that time period

```
#standardSQL
WITH check_times AS (
  SELECT id, start_time AS TIME FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT id, stop_time AS TIME FROM `project.dataset.table` 
), distinct_intervals AS (
  SELECT id, TIME AS start_time, LEAD(TIME) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TIME) stop_time
  FROM check_times
), deduped_intervals AS (
  SELECT a.id, a.start_time, a.stop_time, MAX(some_value) some_value, ANY_VALUE(To_JSON_STRING(b)) event_hash
  FROM distinct_intervals a
  JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
  ON a.id = b.id 
  AND a.start_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.stop_time 
  AND a.stop_time BETWEEN b.start_time AND b.stop_time
  GROUP BY a.id, a.start_time, a.stop_time
), combined_intervals AS (
  SELECT id, MIN(start_time) start_time, MAX(stop_time) stop_time, MAX(some_value) some_value, COUNT(DISTINCT event_hash) events
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT *,
        start_time != IFNULL(LAG(stop_time) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_time), start_time) flag
      FROM deduped_intervals
    )
  )
  GROUP BY id, grp
)
SELECT *
FROM combined_intervals
-- ORDER BY id, start_time
```

with result

```
Row id  start_time  stop_time   some_value  events   
1   1   0           36          50          8    
2   1   41          47          23          1
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Is it possible to add one more column to the result which will show number of events during that time period. In this case the value for this column will be 8 for row 1 and 1 for row 2.

Comment: sure, i will add this shortly to my answer  - meantime  - consider voting up as looks like it helped. also - ideally you should be able to add this by yourself as it is really super simple having that you already have main stuff. so, a) vote up b) confirm you really want me to add this or you will first try by yourself and then if you still have problem i will jump and add it

Comment: oh, I see what you mean  - you tried and was not successful - i see now. will add to my answer later in a day :o)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I modified the last line to this, seems to work but not sure this is optimal solution: select a.id,a.start_time,a.stop_time,a.some_value,count(*) from combined_intervals a full outer join project.dataset.table` b on a.id = b.id AND b.start_time >= a.start_time and b.stop_time <= a.stop_time group by a.id, a.start_time,a.stop_time,a.some_value

Comment: my solution seems to work but i don't think its optimal, its taking too long to run on my data

Comment: see addition to my answer

Comment: make sure you correctly apply my example to your specific case - when I did  - it definitely worked

Answer (score 1):

You can determine when a new grouping starts using a cumulative `max()`.  Then a cumulative conditional `count()` to identify the groups . . . and finally aggregation:

```
select min(start_time), max(stop_time), max(some_value)
from (select t.*,
             countif(prev_stop_time is null or prev_stop_time < start_time) over (partition by id order by start_time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(stop_time) over (partition by id order by start_time rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_stop_time
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by item_id, grp;
```